# How to add multiple link search condition in an Array

Tags: jquery

I am selecting all links that contains certain letters in a url:

```
var links = $('a[href*="abcd"]');
```

How do I add links that contain "abcd" or "xyz"?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ',' to achieve `OR`

```
links = $('a[href*="abcd"],[href*="xyz"]');
```

```js
 links = $('a[href*="abcd"],[href*="xyz"]');

 links.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a href="blahabcd.org">Link abcd</a>
    <a href="blahxyz.org">Link xyz</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize it was this simple :p